# Есть ли решение для динамичного отображения столбцов в GridView Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Необходима возможность динамично отображать/скрывать столбцы в GridView. Желательно чтобы решение запоминалось для пользователя на уровне ДБ, или хранилища браузера.
Пока под эти цели адаптируем RWD Tables, но всплывают подводные камни. Возможно, есть уже что-то готовое, решающее поставленную задачу под Yii2?

Comment: Есть готовый виджет DynaGrid, но там есть много костылей. Мы у себя его до ума доводили, но базовую часть выполняет как надо

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин, как можно получить ваше доведенное до ума решение? 